# Can I autofocus on the first field in a redux-form created using a loop?

Tags: forms, reactjs, focus, redux-form, autofocus

I have created a React component using redux-form and am looking to autoFocus on the first field. The fields are created by looping through an object and creating a field for each item in that object. When I use autoFocus in the JSX is autoFocuses on the last field in the form (which makes sense).

Does anyone know how I can autoFocus on the first field in the form?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class BalanceForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this);
  }
  cancel() {
    //not relevant
  }
  submitForm(e, values) {
    //not relevant
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.props.balanceFormVisible &&
        <div className="modal-background">
          <div className="modal">
            <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
              {Object.keys(this.props.accounts).map((key) => {
                return (
                  this.props.accounts[key].visible &&
                  <div key={this.props.accounts[key].name}>
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor={this.props.accounts[key].name}>
                      {this.props.accounts[key].display}
                    </label>
                    <Field
                      name={this.props.accounts[key].name}
                      component="input"
                      type="number"
                      placeholder=""
                      autoFocus
                    />
                  </div>
                )
              })}
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              <button onClick={ this.cancel } className="cancelbtn" >Cancel</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BalanceForm = reduxForm({form: 'balance'})(BalanceForm)

export default BalanceForm;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How to do If we click a button then form appears dynamically add set focus on first field, It is working fine on index 1 not on index 0. Please advice @Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to this was to conditionally render the form field. Thanks to Alexander Borodin for the inspiration...

```
{Object.keys(this.props.accounts).map((key, i) => {
                console.log(key, i)
                return (
                  this.props.accounts[key].visible &&
                  <div key={this.props.accounts[key].name}>
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor={this.props.accounts[key].name}>
                      {this.props.accounts[key].display}
                    </label>
                    {(i === 0) ? (
                      <Field
                        name={this.props.accounts[key].name}
                        component="input"
                        type="number"
                        placeholder=""
                        autoFocus
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <Field
                        name={this.props.accounts[key].name}
                        component="input"
                        type="number"
                        placeholder=""
                      />
                    )}
                  </div>
                )
              })}
```

Comment: Could this be shorter? We don't need to duplicate Field component code. Something like this:

<Field
                        name={this.props.accounts[key].name}
                        component="input"
                        type="number"
                        placeholder=""
                        {(i===0) ? autoFocus:""}
                      />

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't compile

Comment: Might be, anyway your solution looks fine. (Y)

Comment: How to do If we click a button then form appears dynamically add set focus on first field, It is working fine on index 1 not on index 0. Please advice @Alexander

Answer (score 2):

Some of these either didn't compile or are a bit verbose. This worked for me:

```
    {Object.keys(item)
      .map((key, i) =>
        <div className={`form-row ${key}`} key={key}>
          <label>{key}</label>
          <input value={item[key]}
            type='text'
            onChange={e => {
             this._updateValue(key, e.target.value);
            }}
            autoFocus={i === 0}
          />
        </div>
    )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you hook in to ComponentDidMount, you can ask the DOM to focus the first existing field within the form.

1. Add a ref to the form

   `<form onSubmit={this.submitForm} ref='form'>`
2. Use the ref to focus the element after mounting

   `componentDidMount() {
       const firstInput = this.refs.form.querySelector('input')[0];
       firstInput && firstInput.focus();
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
          {Object.keys(this.props.accounts).map((key, i) => {
            return (
              this.props.accounts[key].visible &&
              <div key={this.props.accounts[key].name}>
                <label className="form-label" htmlFor={this.props.accounts[key].name}>
                  {this.props.accounts[key].display}
                </label>
                <Field
                  name={this.props.accounts[key].name}
                  component="input"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder=""
                  { (i === 0) ? 'autoFocus': ''}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}
```

Comment: This didn't work, but I used the idea to conditionally render the form field based on the value of i. Thanks for the idea!

I'll post my solution below

Comment: How to do If we click a button then form appears dynamically add set focus on first field, It is working fine on index 1 not on index 0. Please advice @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where `autoFocus` wasn't properly passing down from Field to the underlying component. Had to explicitly pass `autoFocus` in the `props` prop for Field.